# TYPO3 - How to add fieldname to Formhandler errorListTemplate.singleWrap typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, html-formhandler

How to add fieldname to Formhandler errorListTemplate.singleWrap typoscript?

I have the following Typoscript :

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {  
  singleErrorTemplate {
    totalWrap = |
    singleWrap = <span class="error">|</span>
  }
  errorListTemplate {
    totalWrap = <div id="liste_erreurs"><ul>|</ul></div>
    singleWrap = <li>|</li>
  }
}
```

And I want to add the current fieldname into the errorListTemplate.singleWrap to get sommething like :

```
errorListTemplate {
  totalWrap = <div id="liste_erreurs"><ul>|</ul></div>
  singleWrap = <li for="[FIELDNAME]">|</li>
}
```

Thanks and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it by jQuery ... it's not as clean as it could be but it worked.